# This pattern attribute in input tag to specify length of password not working?

Tags: html

The pattern attribute is not working, I have included the code below. It is printing the message but when I enter 6 or 7 or 8 characters, it doesn't accept.

```
<input type="password" pattern=".{5,12}" name="password" id="password" required title="Password must be 5 to 12 characters"/>
```

Comment: I have tried the same in jsfiddle, and it seems to be working fine. The only accepted length is in between 5 and 12, and less than 5 or more than 12 are unaccepted. Clean your project and try again, or this might be cookie or cache issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern attribute of the input tag is not supported in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions or Safari 10 and earlier.   Try to use tooltip jquery instead

```
<input type="password" pattern=".{5,12}" name="password" id="password" required title="Password must be 5 to 12 characters" maxlength="12"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

It works on the form submit event. Check out documentation to understand how it works: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Just for a test try to click **Submit** button in the snippet below.

```html
<form>
  <label>Password must be 5 to 12 characters: 
    <input type="password" pattern=".{5,12}" name="password" id="password" required title="Password must be 5 to 12 characters"/>
  </label>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
<form>
```

According to https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-pattern its supported in almost all browsers.